# Replacing part of text string with a page include in Classic ASP

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, include

Not 100% sure if this is possible, but hoping there is a workaround. Several hours of searching bring nothing up.  I have a text string written to the page from a Db table.  If it contains a specific string, I would like to add a page include - example below does write:

```
<!--#include file="members.asp"-->
```

into the text, but does not pull the included file content in.

```
<%=Replace(myQuery("Text"), "123456", "%><!--#include file="mypage.asp"--><% ")%>
```

Client wants it in the page rather than at the top or bottom of the output which would be so easy (and we already do that)  The include has to go in at a specific point in the text.

I would appreciate any help, even if it is to confirm that it is not possible to do this.

Comment: Can't you just always include it in a hidden div and just control it visibility based on the string you get back?

Comment: A file included this way will not actually get included. This isn't going to work.

Comment: Thanks @John - I didn't think it would be possible given that I never found any answers anywhere.

Comment: @Bob - interesting idea, but would I be able to include the div in the exact position - could be 100's of lines down the page.  Any examples of how I would implement that concept?

Comment: Yeah, #includes are executed way before the code is even looked at, so this sort of writing-to-the-page-in-code won't work, and neither will surrounding the #include with some sort of conditional statement. I'd look into something using `Execute` instead (i.e. make sure mypage.asp is all executable vbscript code, and then if conditions are met, read it into a string and execute said string).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body onload="document.getElementById('placeholder').innerText = document.getElementById('alwaysfillme').innerText">
    <p><%=Replace("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "J", "<span id=""placeholder""></span>")%></p>
    <span id="alwaysfillme" style="display:none;"><!--#include file="mypage.asp"--></span>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is what I stuck in "mypage.asp":

```
<% response.Write("--123--") %>
```

When a J is in the text, it displays:

```
ABCDEFGHI--123--KLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

When no J is in the text, it displays:

```
ABCDEFGHIKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

Comment: The down side to this approach is that the content will always be in the page returned; while not rendered, a clever person can view the source to see it. I guess you can clear out the content of "alwaysfillme" but it relies on client side scripts to be enabled. This entire approach depends on that actually.

Comment: Thanks Bob. A little messy perhaps in the sense that it will always show the content, but that's not a major issue, as it is used in several pages across the site. Because the included content was a table, I changed innerText to innerHTML, and for spacing between paragraphs, changed 'span' tags to 'div' tags instead.  Works a treat. Thank you

Comment: Thought it had done the trick, but because I need another onload function to run simultaneously, I either get one or the other depending on which function is put first in 'body Onload'  Is there a way to create then call this as a function (if that will solve the issue of multiple Onloads)  This is what I have in Onload at the moment, but readpano() is not being loaded.   'code'<body onload="document.getElementById('placeholder').innerHTML=document.getElementById('alwaysfillme').innerHTML; readpano();">

Comment: Can you make a new function that performs both, then just call the new function from onLoad? It's been a while for me, so I'm not sure if you can use an onLoad from a tag other than body as well, that might work too.

Answer (score 0):

<%=Replace(myQuery("Text"), "123456", ""&Server.Execute("mypage.asp")&"")%>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).